# How can I make build failure of a custom target stop the building of a dependent target in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I am using CMake to build an application and a collection of plugins.

```
ADD_LIBRARY (plugin_X ...)
ADD_LIBRARY (plugin_Y ...)
ADD_LIBRARY (plugin_Z ...)

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET (all_plugins)
ADD_DEPENDENCIES (all_plugins plugin_X plugin_Y plugin_Z)

ADD_EXECUTABLE (application ...)
ADD_DEPENDENCIES (application all_plugins)
```

The idea is that by running `make application` the plugins will be built as well.

My build scripts rely on `make` returning an error code if the build fails, but if one of the plugins fails to build, `make application` will still succeed.

How can I make the build of `application` fail if its dependencies fail?

Answer (score 0):

On my box, it works correctly.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        printf("Hello world!");
}
```

**a.c**

```
int test(){errorhere}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

ADD_LIBRARY (plugin_X a.c)
ADD_LIBRARY (plugin_Y a.c)
ADD_LIBRARY (plugin_Z a.c)

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET (all_plugins)
ADD_DEPENDENCIES (all_plugins plugin_X plugin_Y plugin_Z)

ADD_EXECUTABLE (application main.c)
ADD_DEPENDENCIES (application all_plugins)
```

Make command

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
make application; echo $?
a.c:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/plugin_X.dir/a.c.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/plugin_X.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/application.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [application] Error 2
2
```